# Link from body shown in footer when testing but not in code

Tags: html, css

sorry for my naivety I'm very new to web development and have to create this for a uni project. The problem I'm having is that I have a grid of image thumbnails that link to full res versions on a separate page, the last image in the grid has a link that shows up and pushes content out the footer and inspect element on the page says the link it within the footer div but in the code it's not there. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.grid {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
  margin: 1.66%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0%;
}


/*  For responsive images */

.content .rs {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.footer a {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'myntieregular';
  src: url('myntie-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 45px;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-color: #c7c7c7;
  border-width: 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="Gallery\DSCF1629.html"><img class="rs" src="Images\Thumbnails\DSCF1629_Thumbnail.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="Gallery\DSCF1425.html"><img class="rs" src="Images\Thumbnails\DSCF1425_Thumbnail.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <div class="content">
      <a href="Gallery\DSCF1723.html"><img class="rs" src="Images\Thumbnails\DSCF1723_Thumbnail.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="Image" alt="Instagram" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
  <a href="link" target="_blank"><img src="Image" alt="Email" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
  <a href="link/" target="_blank"><img src="Image" alt="linkedin" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Learn to use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to close the `<a>` tags within the `"grid"` divs.

It is hard to see since it is so off to the right.